# Cannot browse new IIS, not even from localhost

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I have just setup a new IIS (Windows Server 2008) with a couple of different sites on it. However, I cannot browse any of the sites. Not even from localhost. What happens is that when I try to browse one of the sites, the browser just keeps on trying to load page, but it never gets any response at all (I have checked with Fiddler). The browser just keeps on trying to load the page forever, until I stop it.

- Does not seem to be a firewall issue (since there is the same behaviour from localhost [I added that binding to one of the sites to make sure it works]).
- I tried with a static html file to rule out any basic net-issues. No difference.
- Bindings are setup correct.

What possible causes could there be?

Comment: Is there anything in your `HTTP.SYS` logs? Located in `%SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "telnet localhost 80" (or telnet localhost 80 and check if you get a prompt or not. You will be able to use commands like "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" (then press Enter two times) and get some information. this will tell you if your iis is working or not. If it works then move you will know you are not facing any firewall issues.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> Does not seem to be a firewall issue (since there is the same behaviour from localhost [I added that binding to one of the sites to make sure it works]).

That doesn't mean anything. This absolutely can still be a host-based firewall issue. Try temporarily disabling Windows firewall and see if this fixes the issue.